# On-to Linear Transformation; dimension of kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^6 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be an onto linear transformation (that is, surjective)

What is the minimal value for $\dim(\ker(T))$ , what is the maximal value for $\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))$?

Because $T$ is onto it needs to span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$; therefore  $\dim(\operatorname{im}(T)) \leq 6 $ and $\dim(\ker(T)) \geq 0$ .

Comment: @MorganO If you undelete your answer, I'll up vote it.

Comment: @GitGud I was thinking I should try to get the OP to do some work =) you think I should just answer?

Comment: @MorganO At the time of my comment I was reading the first version of your comment which coincided with the now deleted answer. Do as you wish. If you want to undelete later, ping me and I'll up vote it.

Comment: @MorganO I Updated the asnwer

Comment: @gbox it's true that $\dim \ker T \geq 0$, but you can get a better result by applying the rank nullity theorem. I'd ask you to consider returning the answer posted in the question to its original content. You have changed it significantly so that my answer no longer makes sense (in particular, by changing the bound on the dimension of the image). If you want to post a new answer for verification, you can always put it as a comment.

Comment: @MorganO Thanks, re-edited back, btw. Dim(ker(T)) can be 0?

Comment: @gbox well, you've edited closer to the original... you do know I can look at the edits that have been made, and past versions, right? If $\dim \ker T=0$, then $T$ is injective *and* surjective. This implies it is an isomorphism, and $\mathbb R^6 \simeq \mathbb R^3$. Is this possible? If you just use that $\dim \mathbb R^3 =\dim \operatorname{Im(T)}$ and apply the rank-nullity theorem, this will give you the possible dimension(s).

Comment: @MorganO sorry I got back to the first edit, I have no intention to lie, you are helping me. so the answer is $Dim(Ker(T)) \geq 3$ and $Dim(Im(T) \leq 3$

Comment: @gbox you can say exactly what each of the dimensions must be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16499/discussion-between-gbox-and-morgan-o).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How can $\dim \operatorname{Im}(T)$ be greater than the dimension of the codomain?

Note that, if $T$ is surjective (on-to), then $\operatorname{Im}(T)=\mathbb R^3$. From this, you can deduce the dimension of the image and apply the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) to deduce the dimension of the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $T : V \rightarrow W$ is a linear map of vector spaces, onto means  that $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Im}(T)) = \mathrm{dim}(W).$ Then, you have that $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Im}(T)) + \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(T)) = \mathrm{dim}(V)$ by [rank-nullity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).